# How can I append after a code block?

Tags: cursor-movement

I'm writing code like this:

```
if (!p){
    return 0; <-- cursor is on this line
}
```

And I want to start appending immediately after the code block, like this:

```
if (!p){
    return 0;
}
<-- cursor is on this line, in Insert mode
```

Is there a command for this? Usually I use `jo` to go down a line and then append a new line, or `]}o` if there's more than one line of code inside the brackets, but both of these solutions feel kind of verbose.

Comment: If you do this a lout you can create a key binding.

Comment: In this literal example, it seems easiest to me to do `}i`, which is "go to the end of the paragraph" and "enter insert mode". But in general, I would do `]}o` as you mention, because in the midst of coding I often don't mind the (one) extra keystroke if I spend 0 seconds thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ninja Feet

I made a plugin called [ninja-feet.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet) that, among other things, defines operators `z[` and `z]` for entering Insert mode before and after a text object, respectively. Like other operators, they take a `{motion}`.

For your use case, you could use the `ip` text object: `z]ip`.

#### Caveat

This operator is not repeatable with `.`; it will simply repeat the insertion at the cursor position.

Comment: Why not `z]a}`?

Comment: Because `a}` is a characterwise motion. The operators will work like `i` / `a` for characterwise, and `o` / `O` for linewise. You could use `z]Va}` to force `a}` to be linewise.

Comment: `z]ip` is one more character than the sequence the OP has already dismissed as being too verbose! Upvoted anyway because your plugin looks nifty.

Comment: @Rich, lol. That's certainly true in this case. I'll (weakly) defend myself by saying that verbosity can be measured in different ways: keystrokes is one, and number of actions is another. Technically, `z]ip` is one action whereas `]}o` is two.

Comment: Hahaha. Nice save ;).